# i want location after certain time in android not when i move from one place to another

Tags: android

i want to to get location after certain time so i can define minimum time in method requestslocationupdates. for example i write 60 seconds so i want to get locaiton after 60 seconds. here i got it. but problem is there when i move from one place to another place so also getting locaiton but i dnt want this. i want only location after some interval..

my code is here.

locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

```
    locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    //criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    //criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            provider, 
        0, 
        0, 
        locationListener);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,60000,0,locationListener);
```

Comment: i did it but some time i get also location when i move from one place to another place....i want location exactly some certain time..

Comment: then you must use a `TimerTask`

Comment: if i cant pass minimum time in above method so wat happen first tell me that??  i give u my code link to you i already implemented timer also for that?.................http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976282/i-want-to-know-regarding-how-to-stop-calling-method-which-i-put-in-oncreate-of-se/5976530#5976530

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589963/locationmanager-requestlocationupdates-and-timertask-in-android

Comment: "minTime - the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value." Don't trust the time set in requestlocationupdates to be accurate. Ive heard in some instances that it still reports as often as possible.